# NodeJS and Nested Function for Search Queries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Good day again, hoomans!

I am working with this small web app with **NodeJS**. I have a couple of search functionalities across my web pages. But I want to ask something about nested function in regard to this search functionality.

There is actually no error in my code. It's working pretty well for now, but the reason I am asking this is I don't quite trust my algorithm.

Originally, the structure is that on the back-end part of the search query, the entire code block including the search query to the database is written inside the app.post() method inside my **routes/grades.js** file. The front end on the other hand is written in **AngularJS** in separate file located in **public/javascripts** directory, which should dynamically reload the table elements upon the request using a submit button.

I think this is not a good algorithmic concept because I am thinking of a scenario where multiple users would access the app.post() method and might cause some kind of problem I don't know.

So now, I am thinking if I can make use of nested function with callback and timeout. I cannot describe this anymore clearly so I'll just paste the code in.

Original code in my route:

**routes/grades.js**

```
app.post('/grades', function(req, res, next){
    setTimeout(callback, 100);
    try{
        var reqObj = req.body;
        console.log("Request Object: " + reqObj["className"]);
        req.getConnection(function(err, conn){
            if(err){
                console.error('SQL Connection error: ', err);
                return next(err);
            }
            else{
                var insertSql = "SELECT Class_Name,Class_Code,Class_Instructor FROM classes WHERE Class_Name LIKE ?";
                var insertValues = [
                    '%' + reqObj["className"] + '%'
                ];
                var query = conn.query(insertSql, insertValues, function(err, result){
                    if(err){
                        console.error('SQL error: ', err);
                        return next(err);
                    }
                    var class_array = [];
                    for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
                        class_array.push(result[i]);
                    }
                    console.log(class_array.valueOf());
                    res.send([{
                        info:
                            class_array.valueOf()
                    }])
                });
            }
        });
    }
    catch(ex){
        console.err("Internal error: " + ex);
        return next(ex);
    }
});
```

---

Now, I revised the code in routes/grades.js above and made it something that makes more sense (I think lol), and it works without any error. But then, I still want to know which of these codes have better algorithm, or if they both suck. Lol

**routes/grades.js**

```
router.post('/grades', function(req, res, next){
    searchForClass(req, res, next, function(){
       console.log("Class Search Success");
    });
});

function searchForClass(req, res, next, callback){
    setTimeout(callback, 100);
    try{
        var reqObj = req.body;
        console.log("Request Object: " + reqObj["className"]);
        req.getConnection(function(err, conn){
            if(err){
                console.error('SQL Connection error: ', err);
                return next(err);
            }
            else{
                var insertSql = "SELECT Class_Name,Class_Code,Class_Instructor FROM classes WHERE Class_Name LIKE ?";
                var insertValues = [
                    '%' + reqObj["className"] + '%'
                ];
                var query = conn.query(insertSql, insertValues, function(err, result){
                    if(err){
                        console.error('SQL error: ', err);
                        return next(err);
                    }
                    var class_array = [];
                    for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
                        class_array.push(result[i]);
                    }
                    console.log(class_array.valueOf());
                    res.send([{
                        info:
                            class_array.valueOf()
                    }])
                });
            }
        });
    }
    catch(ex){
        console.err("Internal error: " + ex);
        return next(ex);
    }
};
```

---

Meanwhile, this is my front-end code for the search.

**public/javascripts/app.js**

```
$scope.classFun = function(){
        console.log('clicked submit');
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/grades',
            method: 'POST',
            data: $scope.data
        }).then(function (httpResponse){
            console.log('response', httpResponse);
            // console.log(Object.keys(httpResponse.data[0].info[0]).length);
            var tbody = document.getElementById("class_list_data");
            while(tbody.firstElementChild){
                tbody.removeChild(tbody.firstChild);
            }
            for(var i=0; i<httpResponse.data.length; i++){
                for(var j=0; j<httpResponse.data[i].info.length; j++){
                    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
                    var td = document.createElement("td");
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(httpResponse.data[i].info[j].Class_Name.toString()));
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                    tbody.appendChild(tr);
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

---

I hope I expressed my problem correctly and I really hope you guys can help me.

Much thanks!

Comment: Please consider to post your question to *code review*.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one problem in your code, I don't think you need the callback function because it doesn't give any useful meaning.

```
setTimeout(callback, 100); //it fires the callback after 100ms no matter what
```

You don't have to worry about multiple client requests because each request will be running in different scope.

For performance wise, using MySQL string search with "LIKE" keyword is extremely slow when the table is going big and not indexed correctly.

Comment: Ow okay. So it means that the original code works just fine?

Comment: Basically they are the same.

Comment: Ow okay. I read about this multiple request in nodeJS and I thought it applies to this algorithm... Anyway, thank you very much. Now I know there was nothing wrong on my original code after all. (aside from the "LIKE" key you mentioned). I'll work out on it. Thanks! Cheers!